# data access control in entity framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, view, data-access

I want to make a simple(or not) data access control in Entity Framework. I saw that its not so easily supported in EF, because EF actually doesn't have good support of schemas and views.

I want to make conditional access to some columns of entity.

In Sql Server it's easy to achieve by using schemas. For example I can create a view for user in his schema where some columns are missed. Other user (for example admin) will have all columns in his schema. Both of them can have the same name of the view, for instance: getUsers, but only admin who will execute it from dbo schema(dbo.getUsers) will has all columns, and the others only some. Of course in Sql Server it can be also achieved by stored procedures.

How can I achieve that functionality of data access in EF?

I want to make a function which I will be able to use like this:

```
-- function checks user role and returns appropirate columns/entity  
var result = getAppropirateDataForThisUser("getUsers", user);
```

Of course it is only to illustrate the problem. The usage can be completely different.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to create a wrapper rover DbContext with the logic to filter the columns for relevant user,

```
public class EfWrapper:Context
{
 private DbContext _dbContext;

public EfWrapper(DbContext context){
    _dbContext=context;
  }

  public IEnumerable <User> getUsers(User user){

         //if ... write your logic to choose correct projection 
          var users=  from user in context.Users
          select new UserWithLessColumns
               {
                    id= user.Id,
                    Name= user.Name
               });   
        return users;
 }
}
```

Comment: It could be very hard working with that when I have many entities/views/procedures. Isn't there any simpler solution? Implementing methods for each objects can be bad idea. I would rather to filter the columns on DB site by stored procedure or view...

Comment: In that case.. yes. I think you need to it in the database side.

Comment: Ok, but how can I handle it in EF? I tried to do it by db.ExecuteStoreQuery<User>(@"execute " + schema + "." + procName); but when I execute procedure from schema where I received less columns then EF throw exception that there is not enough columns to do this cast...

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the conditional filtering?  If it's for display, handle that in the upper app layers.  If you're actually talking about different business objects (ie., one user gets one type of object, another user gets a subtype of that object) then you can create different classes, and maps for those classes, and use the code-first EF technique

EF is a data access component, specifically, an Object Relational Mapper, ie., it maps database data to business objects, right?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. Do you have any suggestions how can I achieve that?

Comment: So are you trying to expose different business objects, or filter display?